# nvprof is using all available GPU's when profiling python script

Tags: python, cuda, profiling, nvprof

I am using a remote machine, which has 2 GPU's, in order to execute a Python script which has CUDA code. In order to find where I can improve the performance of my code, I am trying to use `nvprof`.

I have set on my code that I only want to use one of the 2 GPU's on the remote machine, although, when calling `nvprof --profile-child-processes ./myscript.py`, a process with the same ID is started on each of the GPU's.

Is there any argument I can give `nvprof` in order to only use one GPU for the profiling?

Comment: use the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"` to restrict `nvprof` access.  For example `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" nvprof --profile-child-processes ./myscript.py`  would limit nvprof to the first GPU, and `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1" nvprof --profile-child-processes ./myscript.py` would limit it to the 2nd GPU, etc.  The env var is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).  `nvprof --help` shows that it has a `--devices` switch which can limit certain activities to certain GPUs also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, you can use CUDA profilers to profile python codes simply by having the profiler run the python interpreter, running your script:

```
nvprof python ./myscript.py
```

Regarding the GPUs being used, the [CUDA environment variable](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars) `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` can be used to restrict the CUDA runtime API to use only certain GPUs.  You can try it like this:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" nvprof --profile-child-processes python ./myscript.py
```

Also, `nvprof` is [documented](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) and also has command line help via `nvprof --help`.  Looking at the command-line help, I see a `--devices` switch which appears to limit at least some functions to use only particular GPUs.  You could try it with:

```
nvprof --devices 0 --profile-child-processes python ./myscript.py
```

For newer GPUs, `nvprof` may not be the best profiler choice.  You should be able to use [nsight systems](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/) in a similar fashion, for example via:

```
nsys profile --stats=true python ....
```

Additional "newer" profiler resources are linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172153/how-to-profile-in-cuda-application-with-compute-capability-7-x-is-metric-dram/63174624#63174624).