# Like nvidia-smi, can nvidia-occupancy(cuda occupancy) also collect values in real time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I already collect timestream data once every 10 seconds using nvidia-smi. nvidia-occupancy would also like to collect data in this way.

Is there any way to save nvidia-occupancy timeseries data using linux terminal?
Currently, the values that can be easily obtained were only the maximum values.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there isn't any tool to collect occupancy information the way `nvidia-smi` collects its information.

The only way to gather occupancy information is to use one of [the profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172153/how-to-profile-in-cuda-application-with-compute-capability-7-x-is-metric-dram/63174624#63174624).